# Select an element of a listbox with double click Wpf c#

Tags: c#, wpf

In Windows Forms it works without problem. but I would like it to work in wpf. and searched everywhere and I can not find anywhere. how can i make it work in wpf c#

```
   void listBox1_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        int index = this.listBox1.IndexFromPoint(e.Location);
        if (index != System.Windows.Forms.ListBox.NoMatches)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(index.ToString());
        }
    }
```

Comment: Do you want item be selected on DoubleClick only, or Click either? How should item be unselected?

Answer (score 0):

You could setup your own itemcontainer style and use an eventsetter for the mouse double click.

```
<ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type ListBoxItem}}">
        <EventSetter Event="MouseDoubleClick" Handler="ListBoxItem_MouseDoubleClick"/>
    </Style>
</ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
```